# Getting error in the following Java program. Why?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am getting error as "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Pascal.main(Pascal.java:8)"

```
public class Pascal {
    public static void main(String args[]){

    int rows,i,j,k;
    rows=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    double pas[][]= new double[rows][];
    pas[0][0]=1; //the line of error

    for (i=1;i<=rows;i++){
        for (j=1;j<=i;j++){
            pas[i-1][j-1]=pas[i-2][j-2]+pas[i-2][j-1];
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<rows;i++){
        for(j=0;j<=i;j++){
            System.out.print(pas[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

}

Why I am getting error on line: pas[0][0]=1;

Comment: Because since you did not put a number in the second `[]`, that means all of the 2d arrays are NULL. So you would either need to define that size when initializing the variable OR you would need to add the second array in the for-loop such as: `pas[0] = new double[size];` then do `pas[0][0] = 1;`

Answer (score 2):

You only initialize the outer array with `double pas[][]= new double[rows][];`, so `pas[0]` is still `null`, and `pas[0][0]` gives `NullPointerException`.

Change

```
pas[0][0]=1;
```

to

```
pas[0] = new double[1];
pas[0][0]=1;
```

You also have to call `pas[i] = new double[some-length];` for the other rows.

Answer (score 1):

you didnt initialise your array properly

```
double pas[][]= new double[rows][here columns are missing];
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the initialization the OP wants, since it looks like he's building a triangle, so the number of columns should be different for each row.

Answer (score 0):

In two dimensional array, you have to specify the column size also.

```
double pas[][]= new double[rows][cols];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.survey.ui;

class demo {
public static void main(String args[]){

    int rows,i,j,k;
    rows=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    double pas[][]= new double[rows][Integer.parseInt(args[0])];
    pas[0][0]=1;

    for (i=2;i<=rows;i++){
        for (j=2;j<=i;j++){
            pas[i-1][j-1]=pas[i-2][j-2]+pas[i-2][j-1];
        }
    }


    for(i=0;i<rows;i++){
        for(j=0;j<=i;j++){
            System.out.print(pas[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
}
```

I am not aware of your business logic but above will  run.